# Can't suppress DriverManager's static initializer block

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, powermock

I have a unit test that attempts to create a `SQLException` to simulate a database error. In `SQLException`'s constructor, there is a call to `DriverManager`, which has a static initialization block. I figured that I could suppress the static block with this type of setup:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor({"java.sql.DriverManager"})
public class StaticTest 
{
    @Test
    public void testStaticSuppress() throws Exception
    {
        SQLException ex = new SQLException();
        expect(...).andThrow(ex);
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the static block in `DriverManager` is still called. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Clarifications**

- I am running Powermock 1.5 - I was under the impression that using v1.5 allows me to mock system classes
- When `DriverManager` runs it's static initialization block, I get this exception:

> Oct 15, 2013 1:06:24 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans
>
> WARNING: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
>
> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver, and the class loader (instance of ) for resolved class, java/lang/management/ManagementFactory, have different Class objects for the type javax/management/MBeanServer; used in the signature

- I realize that I could make a mock of `SQLException` and never instantiate it directly. I would rather not go that route since it would mean updating 91 different unit tests. I asked the question because it looked like my code should work just fine according to the PowerMock docs.

Comment: Is it relevant for your tests to suppress the initialization of `DriverManager`?

Comment: It is relevant for my tests to be able to simulate database errors. The easiest way to do that would be to create `SQLException`s, but that has a bunch of side-effects due to `DriverManager`

Comment: The static initializer of `DriverManager` registers the drivers on the classpath. I am curious how this could cause side effects in your tests, unless you're testing a JDBC driver implementation itself.

Comment: It tries to register drivers on the classpath. I don't want that. It logs exceptions when I don't have any drivers, since I'm running with a unit testing classpath. I don't want that. I'm trying to test my error handling of a database error without running JDBC code. Since I'm testing components in isolation, I don't want to run extra/external code.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the Powermock docs, I'm setting up my test to do just that, but my test is still running the external code.

Comment: `DriverManager` itself only logs exceptions to its internal `logWriter` (a `PrintWriter`) and that is `null` unless explicitly set, so you shouldn't have any observable effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (but I am not certain) that Powermock is unable to prevent the static initializer from running for classes that are loaded by the system or bootstrap classloader (like the jre classes including those of the package `java.sql` are).

---

After posting to the Powermock Google Group, I got [this response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/powermock/6WqENatIqQU/8nKIUUAjZOAJ):

> You can mock, suppress methods, stub methods etc in these classes since powermock 1.2.5 but you cannot suppress static initializers.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem) seem to say that they fixed this in Powermock 1.2.5, and I'm running 1.5 (see my update). Is that a valid conclusion or am I misreading the docs?

Comment: Based on that link I'd say what you try should work, but I am just not sure.

Comment: Well, your answer is useful information for < 1.2.5 users. Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Turns out, you're right. I updated your answer with some info from the Google Group

Answer (score 2):

See this page: [Google Groups PowerMock Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/TGkZlY4Pjck)

You need to add to the class: `@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")`

Comment: Adding this on the class level didn't eliminate the WARNING but linkage error disappeared and now the test is running fine.