# Java Mocking DriverManager

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, powermock

I am trying to write a unit test for a method that called `DriverManager.getConnection()`. I am using PowerMock 1.5 and easymock. Somehow, Powermock is unable to mock DriverManager and ends up calling real DriverManager. 
This is how my code looks like:-

```
@Test
public void checkConnection() {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/orcl";
        String password = "@55";
        String dbName = "Halloween";
        String username = "Dracula";

        PowerMock.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);

        Connection connection = EasyMock.createMock(Connection.class);
        List<Datasource> allDs = new ArrayList<Datasource>(2);
        Datasource d1 = new Datasource();
        d1.setUrl(url);
        allDs.add(d1);
        allDs.add(new Datasource());

        EasyMock.expect(hibernateTemplate.find("from Datasource ds where ds.dsName = ?", dbName)).andReturn(allDs);

        EasyMock.expect(DriverManager.getConnection(d1.getUrl(), username, password)).andReturn(connection);

        PowerMock.replay(DriverManager.class);
        EasyMock.replay(hibernateTemplate);

        Connection con = testee.authenticateUserForDatabase(dbName, username, password);
        Assert.assertNotNull(con);

        PowerMock.verify(DriverManager.class);
        EasyMock.verify(hibernateTemplate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My class code is as shown below:-

```
 @Override
public Connection getConnection(String dbName, String username, String password) {
    Connection connection = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Datasource> ds = hibernateTemplate.find("from Datasource ds where ds.dsName = ?", dbName);
    if (ds == null || ds.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ProviderException("Invalid datasource name [" + dbName + "]");
    }
    Datasource d = (Datasource) ds.get(0);
    int retryCount = 0;
    boolean connected = false;
    while (retryCount < 2 && !connected) {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(d.getUrl(), username, password);
            LOG.info("Connected successfully to [{}]", dbName);
            connected = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.warn("Error: [{}] occured. Going to retry, attempt # [{}]", e.getMessage(), (retryCount + 1));
            retryCount++;
            connected = false;
        }
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: If you don't like my suggestion below, you could also introduce a ConnectionProvider interface into your class that has the getConnection(). Then you could mock ConnectionProvider.

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that this is a concrete class that is loaded by the bootstrap or system classloader.

Answer (score 0):

You might instead use the javax.sql.DataSource instead of using DriverManager.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html

This way, you are working with an interface you can Mock. Most applications these days use the DataSource interface and do not interact with the DriverManager like this.

So your code could then have an api like:

```
public class DataSourceFactory {
  public DataSource getDataSource( String url, String usr, String pwd);
}
```

And you could implement the real DataSource using DriverManager if you wish, and then mock DataSourceFactory for your unit test.

Comment: Thanks. That is always an option. Even when I create connectionfactory. I may need to use Drivermanager. Question remain - why can't we mock Drivermanager? I tried suppressing static block as well but no use :(

Comment: "Why can't we mock DriverManager?" Because Powermock does some advanced bytecode manipulation in its ClassLoader but there are still some Java system classes / packages that get loaded before PowerMock can touch them. java.sql.* is one of them. See this thread (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/6WqENatIqQU) and this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386542/cant-suppress-drivermanagers-static-initializer-block). You might also check this page on mocking System classes (https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem).

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround in case you can't mock the `DriverManager.getConnection` static invocation is just skip it.

Extract the static invocation to a protected method in your sut with the same signature than the static method.

```
protected Connection driverManagerGetConnection(String url, String user, String password){
  return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
}
```

Now, in your test, use [EasyMock to create a partial mock](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/IMockBuilder.html) of your sut, mocking the `driverManagerGetConnection` method.

```
public void testFoo{

  // setup: sut
  YourSutClass sut = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(YourSutClass.class)
                 .addMockedMethod("driverManagerGetConnection").createMock();

  ...

  // setup: expectations
  EasyMock.expect(sut.driverManagerGetConnection()).andReturn(mockConnection);
  ...

  // exercise
  EasyMock.replay(sut, mockConnection);
  sut.whatever();

  // verify
  EasyMock.verify(sut, mockConnection);
}
```

With this approach the only line you leave untested is the invocation to the static method.